# Boot Ubuntu from USB

Tags: dual-boot

I have a laptop with Windows 8.1. I'm going to use a USB stick to dual boot Ubuntu from. I only wish to install the boot and swap on the USB, for /home I'm going to use a partition from the hard-drive for Ubuntu to install.

How should I proceed setting this up?

Comment: What "rest" do you mean?  Are you saying you want to put your home partition on the hard drive?

Comment: you better install whole ubuntu on the usb...

Comment: I could do that, although I have a 500GB drive I prefer to use vs my 32GB USB.

Comment: This isn't a full answer to your question but I wanted to make sure that you know that installing a swap partition on a USB flash driver will greatly decrease the drives lifespan because it will result in a high number of read/writes. This will of course vary depending on the quality of the flash chip but USB flash drives often have cheap flash chip. Back to your original question if you are willing to do a full reinstall the advanced installer settings should (at least they used to) allow you to select which drives you want to put those partitions on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going use a USB stick, you certainly do not have to install it next to Windows on your hard drive. Ubuntu runs just fine off the USB. In fact, you do not even have to have a hard drive installed on your laptop for the USB stick UBUNTU OS to work (although to get Ubuntu on the stick, you will have to have a computer with Windows and a wired Internet connection so you can install Ubuntu with Wi-Fi (Broadcom plug-in) on the stick).

You must be connected to the Internet for this procedure to work.

Use the installer located at http://www.pendrivelinux.com   and click on "DOWNLOAD UUI"
using a Windows based machine.

Go to Ubuntu.com and download the 14.04 LTS 32 bit Desktop .iso image file (I used 32 bit because of memory limitations. BTW it works great!)

Plug in your USB Stick (I used a 4GB blank USB stick)

Start the Universal USB installer. Follow the prompts to install Ubuntu on your USB stick.

This will take a few minutes so be patient. Use a small persistence file..about 1MB.

After installation, (the program will tell you when it is completed).

After you install Ubuntu, you may have to download the proprietary Broadcom driver for your wireless Wi-Fi connection to work. Do this now before unplugging your USB stick. 
Shutdown Windows and boot from the USB to start Ubuntu. After booting, choose "System Settings > Additional drivers" and Ubuntu will find the Broadcom Wi-Fi driver
automatically. then choose install.

Remove your USB stick if you wish.

Plug into any computer with a motherboard. Go to setup on your motherboard and choose boot from USB as the first boot attempt.

You will be pleasantly surprised when the Ubuntu OS boots. You may have to add and setup your Wi-Fi if you have a wireless router.

Any other questions just ask!

Greg Petranek.......Ubuntu user and Linux supporter.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative. But I still want to have Ubuntu installed on the USB stick as asked. I would have more than Ubuntu itself installed on the USB, such as Fedora.